# How can I define http.route(‘URL’) which will generic for all pages or dynamic url with dynamic page rendering in odoo 11 web controller?

Tags: http, web, controller, routes, odoo-11

I want to use below method which is call while rendering any page. If I pass ‘/’ in http.route it will call only for homepage not for others like ‘/shop’, ‘/blog’ etc. Also wanted to pass dynamic template rendering in return on the basis of http.route(‘URL’).

`@http.route(['/'], type='http', auth="public", website=True) 
def cusotm_controller_func(self, **kwargs):
    values= { # values which is passing in template }
return request.render('website.homepage', values)`

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to call your function in another moment, like after the models registry(pool) is loaded. You could do this by implementing the method `_register_hook` in your model. Odoo will always call that method in your model to allow you to initialize whatever you want, but you just have the self and cr arguments.

Maybe helps

Thanks to from odoo forum.

## Solution :

Controllers are registering itself in the openerp.http.controllers_per_module dict ([see code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/odoo/http.py#L881))... so you can get controller instance using module name and controller name under it:

```
from odoo.http import controllers_per_module

controller_instance = None
for name,instance in controllers_per_module.get('my_module'):
    if name.endswith('my_module.controller.name'):
        controller_instance = instance
        break
if controller_instance != None:
    controller_instance.a_function(*args)
```